# Python ImportError: No module named - Works in ssh but not in browser

Tags: python, runtime-error, internal

Not sure what the issue is. Works fine via ssh. When viewed in a browser I get a server error. This is know working code that has been migrated to another server / environment.

It can not find a module that is clearly in the directory. Have checked permissions on files and they look ok 755.

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

```
ImportError: No module named xmlproducts
mod_python (pid=16232, interpreter='realtechy.com', phase='PythonHandler', handler='mod_python.cgihandler'): Application error
ServerName: 'realtechy.com'
DocumentRoot: '/var/www/vhosts/realtechy.com/httpdocs'
URI: '/products/myproducts.py'
Location: None
Directory: '/var/www/vhosts/realtechy.com/httpdocs/'
Filename: '/var/www/vhosts/realtechy.com/httpdocs/products/myproducts.py'
PathInfo: ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch\n    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1229, in _process_target\n    result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1128, in _execute_target\n    result = object(arg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mod_python/cgihandler.py", line 96, in handler\n    imp.load_module(module_name, fd, path, desc)
File "/var/www/vhosts/realtechy.com/httpdocs/products/myproducts.py", line 6, in <module>\n    import xmlproducts
ImportError: No module named xmlproducts
```

Comment: Depending on how the Python executable is called, the contents of `sys.path` (the module search path) can be different.  Try printing `sys.path` before the failed import so you can verify that the directory containing `xmlproducts` is there.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the module is not installed properly (or at all).  To verify, do the following:

1. open a shell and start the python shell by typing `python`
2. enter the commmand `help('modules')`
3. review the list of modules that's returned to see whether `xmlproducts` is included
4. if not, then install the module